# Energy functional

Tags: ricci-flow, mp.mathematical-physics, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

During my study on [Ricci Flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_flow) I faced some functional known as [energy functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_functional). For example Einstein-Hilbert functional is called an energy functional, also in Perelman's works $\mathcal{F}(g,f)=\int_M(R+|\nabla f|^2)e^{-f}d\mu$ is introduced as an energy functuional, where $M$ is a closed manifold, $g$ is Riemannian metric, $R$ is Ricci scalar, and $f$ is any function that in the physics literature is called [dilaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilaton).

I do not know why these functionals are attributed to the energy concept and why does $f$ show dilaton concept?

Can anyone help me? thanks for your attention!

Comment: It's just names, not important for understanding Ricci flow and Perelman's work. Btw, Perelman himself called pretty much everything that is monotone *entropy* (not energy).

Answer (score 3):

The name energy comes from kind of Physics motivation. These functions decrease (or increase) monotonically under Ricci flow. And energy function is extremal at a fixed point of the flow. In physics total energy is extremal for the static solutions of equation of motions.

In fact in the context of string theory, consistency of a target manifold ( similar to equation of motion for the metric of target manifold) is given by Ricci flat condition and some equation for a scalar field (dilaton). Moreover an energy function shows up with precisely the form given.

Answer (score 2):

I was under the impression that the name came from the theoretical use. The idea being to obtain [Ricci flow as a gradient](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/04/24/285a-lecture-8-ricci-flow-as-a-gradient-flow-log-sobolev-inequalities-and-perelman-entropy/#more-361) flow of some functional, in the way that solutions to the heat equation are gradient flow of the Dirichlet energy $E(u) = \int |\nabla u|^2 dx$.

As for the dilation, I'm not sure, but it may be that $f$ suppose to be a conformal factor on the metric which only changes the magnitude of the metric pointwise.

Comment: your Dirichlet energy is not correct!

Comment: Dirichlet's energy: $E(u)=\int |\nabla u|^2 dV$

Comment: Ooops! Yes Dirichlet energy is integral of gradient squared, not integral of Hessian....